# General compiler command-line syntax : where to find a reference

Tags: compiler-construction, reference

As far as I can see, most C and C++ compilers - be it GNU Compiler Collection, be Intel, among others - share a very similar command-line syntax. But I have not found a general reference what this de-facto standard constitutes, not to speak of any subtle differences between different vendors.

Hence I would like to see such a general reference in order to obtain more knowledge on how compilers work and how better communicate what I want. I am especially interested in non-source issues like linking, because of the cryptic errors these regularly produce.

I have been searching on the web for this, but without success.

Thanks!

PS: I use Linux, if details depend on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem is that most programmers never actually see their compiler's command line.   It's usually hidden behind a GUI or a make file.

Second, most programmers only use one compiler on one platform, so don't care about commonalities with other compilers.

So, basically, you are looking for a reference that will be used by the build-master at a few cross-pltform companies.  You are probably talking about less than 100 people in the US.